# How do I get a list of all currently loaded assemblies?

Tags: c#, reflection

> How do I get a list of all currently
>   loaded assemblies?

**Closed as a duplicate of [How do you loop through currently loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currenlty-loaded-assemblies)**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
Assembly[] asms = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```