# How do I list all loaded assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

In .Net, I would like to enumerate all loaded assemblies over all AppDomains. Doing it for my program's AppDomain is easy enough `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. Do I need to somehow access every AppDomain? Or is there already a tool that does this?

Comment: Note that `GetAssemblies()` won't work, as it is not recursive and it will miss out any nested assembly references. I've added a recursive version of `GetAssemblies()` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies/26300241#26300241.

Comment: @Contango: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` is perfectly fine.  It doesn't need to walk references recursively, because it isn't enumerating references in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you loop through currently loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**Using Visual Studio**

1. Attach a debugger to the process (e.g. start with debugging or Debug > Attach to process)
2. While debugging, show the Modules window (Debug > Windows > Modules)

This gives details about each assembly, app domain and has a few options to load symbols (i.e. pdb files that contain debug information).

[image]

**Using Process Explorer**

If you want an external tool you can use the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (freeware, published by Microsoft)

Click on a process and it will show a list with all the assemblies used. The tool is pretty good as it shows other information such as file handles etc.

**Programmatically**

Check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currenlty-loaded-assemblies) question that explains how to do it.

Comment: It's even better than explained here, because in the properties page for a process, Process Explorer shows exactly which AppDomain (including the 'Shared Domain') assemblies are loaded into. So it shows more than just which .dlls are loaded into the process. It would be nice to know what APIs they use to show this (the 'Programmatically' link about will just give the Assemblies in the CurrentDomain).

Answer (score 25):

Here's what I ended up with.  It's a listing of all properties and methods, and I listed all parameters for each method.  I didn't succeed on getting all of the values.

```
foreach(System.Reflection.AssemblyName an in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()){
    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(an.ToString());
    foreach(Type type in asm.GetTypes()){
        //PROPERTIES
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties()){
            if (property.CanRead){
                Response.Write("<br>" + an.ToString() + "." + type.ToString() + "." + property.Name);
            }
        }
        //METHODS
        var methods = type.GetMethods();
        foreach (System.Reflection.MethodInfo method in methods){
            Response.Write("<br><b>" + an.ToString() + "."  + type.ToString() + "." + method.Name  + "</b>");
            foreach (System.Reflection.ParameterInfo param in method.GetParameters())
            {
                Response.Write("<br><i>Param=" + param.Name.ToString());
                Response.Write("<br>  Type=" + param.ParameterType.ToString());
                Response.Write("<br>  Position=" + param.Position.ToString());
                Response.Write("<br>  Optional=" + param.IsOptional.ToString() + "</i>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw...  I excluded it from the initial post, but I filtered some of the responses like so `foreach(Type type in asm.GetTypes()){  
    if ((type.ToString().IndexOf("ACLASSIMLOOKINGFOR")>=0) || (type.ToString().IndexOf("BCLASSIMLOOKINGFOR")>=0)){...`

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Instead of using GetExecutingAssembly(), I used GetEntryAssembly() to ensure I'm getting a better list of Assemblies used by my program. If the ExecutingAssembly happens to be a DLL, I'm going to miss out on a few of them.

Comment: try using: Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

Comment: To enumerate loaded assemblies you call Assembly.Load() ?? What a nonsense!

Answer (score 0):

Using the command prompt `cmd.exe` you just have to type

```
tasklist /M
```

in the console and it will list down all the process with all the `dll` loaded by process. If that things went too fast in the console you can copy it to clipboard as

```
tasklist /M |clip
```

and paste it to notepad.