# How can I get a list of files loaded by my process?

Tags: .net, deployment, sysinternals

I'm trying to do a quick and dirty deployment of a project.  I thought it would be easy to run my process, use some tool to grab a list of all loaded files (DLLs) and use that list to create a copy file list for my test deployment.

Thought about using filemon but there is a lot of noise in there.  Its a .net project.

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currenlty-loaded-assemblies

Comment: @GrayWizardx So why don't you vote to close it then?  That's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I agree that question is getting at the same point as mine, although I would like to figure it out without coding that logic into my project.  I haven't seen a good way to do this

Comment: What's wrong with coding this into your project?

Comment: Looks like what they need is not exactly the same as TheSean wants it to deploy the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use .NET's Reflection to analyze your application AppDomain(s) and dump a list of loaded assemblies and locations.

```
var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
foreach (var assembly in loadedAssemblies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetName().Name);
    Console.WriteLine(assembly.Location);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, although not what I was hoping for.  I didn't want to add code to my project to accomplish this.  But looks like it will work.

Comment: Note that `GetAssemblies()` won't work consistently, as it is not recursive and it will miss out any nested assembly references. I've added a recursive version of `GetAssemblies()` at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies/26300241#26300241.

Answer (score 1):

Process Explorer?

Comment: I think so...or some of the other sysinternals stuff..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980429/why-windows-7-isnt-written-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`AppDomain.GetAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx)

```
For Each Ass As Reflection.Assembly In CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    Console.WriteLine(Ass.ToString())
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies) already.

The gist of it is use current appdomain to get a list of assemblies and loop through their loader location.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question, to do a fast deployment you can set in all the references of your project but the Framework ones the setting "Copy Local" to true.

This way when you build your application you will have all the needed DLLs at your output directory (well, almost all, references needed by your references won't be copied automatically, so it's best to add them as a local reference too).

Hope this helps. If not, just say why, I will try to continue on this.

Comment: thanks, wish it was that simple.  the way our app is designed is that we have a lot of references loaded at run time.  this is what makes it such a pain to figure out.  We basically have a bin folder with hundreds of DLLs in it.  my project only needs a subset.  I *could* just copy all but its way more MBs than I need.