# Get Full Class Path using Reflection

Tags: c#

I try to get Full namespace path of given class name 
example like 
input class name ="ABC"

a class ABC located on A.B namespace

i need full path like A.B.ABC

my input type pass in string like name of class not type

Type t= Type.GetType("A.B.ABC"); working

Type t= Type.GetType("ABC"); not working

how to find A.B.ABC on ABC

Code :

```
 public partial class UcDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    private string _ClassFullName = "UcDataGridView";

    [Browsable(true), Category("Misc")]
    public string ClassFullName
    {
        get
        { return _ClassFullName; }
        set
        {
            _ClassFullName = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ClassFullName))
            {
                ClassType = Type.GetType(_ClassFullName);

                if (ClassType != null)
                {
                    if (ClassType.IsClass)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo[] props = ClassType.GetProperties();
                        foreach (var item in props)
                        {
                            var txtCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                            txtCol.Name = "C" + item.Name;
                            txtCol.HeaderText = item.Name;
                            txtCol.DataPropertyName = item.Name;
                            txtCol.ReadOnly = true;
                            this.Columns.Add(txtCol);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        this.Columns.Clear();
                }
                else
                    this.Columns.Clear();
            }
            else
                this.Columns.Clear();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    private Type ClassType { get; set; }

    public UcDataGridView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Comment: What wrong with `typeof(ABC).ToString()` ?

Comment: `ABC.cs` is a filename, not a class name.

Comment: `typeof(ABC).FullName` would be more explicit, and doesn't rely on the behaviour of `ToString()`.

Comment: What does `.cs` have to do with this? In what context does your code run, are you reading `.cs` files or is the file compiled and the class `ABC` present in or known to your assembly?

Comment: .cs is the extension of a file name

Comment: I know about typeof but class located in a.b namespace it is not working.

Comment: Type t= Type.GetType("A.B.ABC"); it's working but only name of the class pass in input.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with

```
typeof(ABC).FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fullPathName= typeof(className).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(_Default).UnderlyingSystemType
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to scan your assembly for classes with the same name:

```
ClassType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UcDataGridView)).GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == _ClassFullName);
```

You have to be certain that `UcDataGridView` does not appear more than once in the same assembly.

Comment: One option is to scan the executing assembly, which is retrieved with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`. However you can also search the referenced assemblies as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies#answer-8304132).