# How to distinguish DLL files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, dll-injection

I have a program that gets every module loaded into a process and compares them with a database of forbidden DLL files, which works just fine, but it's too simple to circumvent (just change the name of dll file which you want to inject into the process). So I'm asking how can I distinguish DLL files. Is there any unique identifier which can be used in C#? Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the program I'm creating checks dll files of another program not created by me which is written in C++.

Comment: There very well [could be...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: When the forbidden files are signed it's very easy. But they probably aren't. You should elaborate on the actual situation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry, no they aren't signed.

Comment: Then you'll have to come up with a better definition/signature for the forbidden dlls. Not likely anyone here can come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through every module loaded in a process [How do I list all loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies) and see if there is a properly of each [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) such as [ModuleVersionId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.moduleversionid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that does not change when the filename is changed?

Comment: You could use LoadForReflection and check for certain clasess. But the question isn't clear about the definitions.

Comment: @sevzas I forgot to mention that I'm checking the dll files on other application which I didn't create, so if I'm right, I can't acess the "ModuleVersionId". I searched a bit more and found "ModuleMemorySize". I know that it isn't unique, but the chances that the sizes will meet is very low. What do you think?

Comment: So your checker program examines the modules in *other* .net processes?

Comment: Then you're working with ProcessModule class which doesn't offer much.  There is one thing I noticed: you maintain a list of *forbidden* dlls yet all comments allude to a list of *permitted* dlls.

Comment: @sevzas Sorry if I misled you. I get all modules from the process and check if there are any forbidden DLLs (DLLs I don't want to be injected into the process).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is even remotely a decent way of handling it, but maybe try hashing the DLL file and check against known trusted hashes of the files? this would require you to already have a trusted list of dll hashes but should safeguard against simply renaming to bypass your current security measure.