# Is there a C# equivalent of navigator.plugins and/or navigator.mimetypes

Tags: javascript, c#, plugins, jquery-plugins, navigator

Is there any equivalent C# solution to the JavaScript navigator.plugins object which returns an array of plugin names?  I need to do the equivalent of this in C# (for reasons too detailed to describe here!)

I cannot fathom how navigator.plugins would (if it could) determine its returned array list from the Windows Registry alone, so I suspect that it must be looking at loaded (or referenced) system Assemblies as well as - perhaps - other Windows files, but thus far, its logic has defeated me.

Does anyone have any ideas (or links to any source code) that may assist me?  Thanks in advance for any clues....

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458362/how-do-i-list-all-loaded-assemblies) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike.   Um, I think that some of the Assembly routines might be useful, but I also feel in my bones that the Registry needs to be included (somehow) as well ...