# c# application: how to view the loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

The depends.exe tool can walk thru all the dll's that the executable depends to, but if the DLL is loaded by the Assembly class dynamically at runtime, how can I see the already loaded DLLs(assemblies)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you loop through currently loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a snapshot:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

As they happen:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad
```

Something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += AssemblyLoad;
    LogCurrent("before");
    AnotherMethod();
    LogCurrent("after");
}
static void AnotherMethod()
{
    // to force stuff to happen
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand().Dispose(); 
}
static void LogCurrent(string caption)
{
    foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(caption + ": " + asm.FullName);
    }
}

static void AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is an external tools like depends.exe to view the loaded assemblies.

Comment: If it is loading the dll at runtime, then it could be getting the string from anywhere. The only way to monitor it is *at* runtime. You could use windbg/sos, and attach to the process?

Comment: WinDbg must be the most convenient way. You can simply use "lm" to list all modules, both native and managed.

Comment: Should `AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)` return `Assembly` and *not* be of `void`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're not messing with AppDomains:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you are looking for external tool ?  Try WinDbg with SOS debugging extension; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx.

There are other tools that might be easier to use that provide the same level of detail.  I think the folks over at JetBrains have one ( Resharper )

Answer (score 1):

fuslogw can help with this, it has an option for monitoring all assembly bindings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx