# Provide multiple services using MS DI

Tags: .net-core

I want provide a services to do GetPhone()

like this

```
provider.GetService<People>().GetPhone(iphone4S).Use<IPhone>(phone => phone.Call("123456"));
```

and I try in People() to do GetPhone() but it's no way

how to do this services？

my Services Code

```
public interface IPhone
{
    string Call(string Num);
}
public class People 
{
    private IPhone _phone;
    public People(IPhone phone) => this._phone = phone;

    public void Use<TPhone>(Action<IPhone> config)
        where TPhone : class, IPhone
    {
        config(this._phone);
    }
    public IPhone GetPhone()
    {
        return this._phone;
    }
}
public class iphone4S : IPhone
{
    ....
}

public class iphone5S : IPhone
{
    ....
}
```

Main program:

```
ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
         .AddSingleton<People>()
         .BuildServiceProvider();
Provider.GetService<People>().GetPhone(iphone4S).Use<IPhone>(phone => phone.Call("123456"));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to use different implementations for a service based on the current model, just detect the model during runtime and register only the appropriate service. If you want to find an object based on some user-provided data though, you are asking for data retrieval, not dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ability to use multiple implementations (`iphone4S`, `iphone5S`) of the same interface (`IPhone`). There is no built-in support of this scenario by Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. However there are numerous workarounds for this limitation. One of the best in my opinion (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177920/5740031)) is the registering of factory and creation of required instances based on input parameter.

To use it, you should inject not an `IPhone` to `People` constructor, but factory `Func<Type, IPhone>`. Then in `Use` method where you know the type of implementation (`TPhone`) you create an instance with injected factory:

```
public class People
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IPhone> phoneFactory;
    private IPhone _phone;

    public People(Func<Type, IPhone> phoneFactory) => this.phoneFactory = phoneFactory;

    public void Use<TPhone>(Action<IPhone> config) where TPhone : class, IPhone
    {
        _phone = phoneFactory(typeof(TPhone));
        config(this._phone);
    }

    public IPhone GetPhone()
    {
        return this._phone;
    }
}
```

In Main() method you should just register the factory and all possible implementations:

```
ServiceProvider provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<People>()
    .AddTransient<iphone4S>()
    .AddTransient<iphone5S>()
    .AddTransient(factory => (Func<Type, IPhone>)(type => (IPhone)factory.GetService(type)))
    .BuildServiceProvider();

provider.GetService<People>().Use<iphone5S>(phone => phone.Call("123456"));
```

**UPDATE**

If you have a long list of implementations for `IPhone` interface, you could register them with reflection based approach:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<People>()
    .AddTransient(factory => (Func<Type, IPhone>)(type => (IPhone)factory.GetService(type)));

foreach (var iphoneType in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
    .Where(t => typeof(IPhone).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
{
    services.AddTransient(iphoneType);
}

var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
provider.GetService<People>().Use<iphone5S>(phone => phone.Call("123456"));
```

This will work if implementation classes are defined in the same assembly where `Main()` method resides. If implementation are defined in different assemblies, you could adjust this approach by enumerating all loaded assemblies, like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383690/5740031).

Comment: The phone model won't change between DI configuration and call. The OP shouldn't have to *specify* what service to use, just register the appropriate one

Comment: Then why OP specified `TPhone` as parameter in `Use<TPhone>` call?

Comment: that's a very interesting question. I suspect it's a case of the XY Problem.

Comment: Selecting specific implementation at run-time is a valid scenario. Mark Seemann in his great book "Dependency Injection in .NET" devotes whole section to this problem (6.1. Mapping runtime values to Abstractions).

Comment: I didn't say it isn't. There's no point in registering 10 variants though when only one can be used and that is know at startup time

Comment: thk.@CodeFuller it's good anwser,but I have other question. if I have 4s~100s so I need to one by one to addtion AddTransient<T>()?

Comment: Check update of my answer for registering long list of implementations.