# How to check if assembly is loaded

Tags: c#

I need to check if an assembly is loaded when running my code.

I need to check if an assembly is loaded when running my code and to convert it to bool because if the users doesn´t have the .dll installed the application crashes.
I need something like that:

```
if ( // assembly is loaded = true )
{
    //run something
}
```

Comment: One of these 2 could help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyload?view=netframework-4.7.2 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you loop through currently loaded assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies)