# Strategy to ensure assemblies are loaded during unit testing in ADO and are counted against testing metrics

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, test-coverage

So I ran into a bit of an embarrassing situation recently where my test coverage via pipeline was fantastic but a bug came out, and root cause analysis found that it was in a very small project/dll/library that wasn't referenced by unit tests at all so ADO didn't actually list it in the assemblies tested against Some 200 lines of untested code. I think the new project got put in during a crunch as part of a very large commit, but somehow we managed to unit test around it. Obviously not ideal -- I'd like to get some sort of warning if a project that we build isn't unit tested.

I'm considering doing some sort of hinky "Load every DLL who's name starts with [prefix] scheme as part of the test project, but that's custom and dumb and it seems like there has got to be a better way. I'm using MSTest for my test framework, so if there's something built in there that would be ideal.

Comment: You need to make sure that the test project has a reference to the assembly you want to test. If the assembly is not referenced, it won’t be loaded during the test run and won't be analyzed by code coverage. This is by design. You can try to list all the loaded assemblies and check if any assembly is missing. See [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383686/how-do-you-loop-through-currently-loaded-assemblies) for more info.